# Identify how often an action A is the first action in a session

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a Spark dataframe as follows:

```
val data = Seq(
    (1, 1, "A"),
    (1, 2, "A"),
    (1, 3, "X"),
    (1, 4, "A"),
    (2, 1, "A"),
    (2, 2, "X"),
    (2, 3, "Y"),
    (3, 1, "X"),
    (3, 2, "Y"),
    (4, 1, "X"),
    (4, 2, "A"),
    (4, 3, "Y")
  )

val df = data.toDF("session", "actionNr", "action")
```

```
df =
+---------+----------+--------+
+ session | actionNr | action |
+---------+----------+--------+
| 1       | 1        | A      |
| 1       | 2        | A      |
| 1       | 3        | X      |
| 1       | 4        | A      |
| 2       | 1        | A      |
| 2       | 2        | X      |
| 2       | 3        | Y      |
| 3       | 1        | X      |
| 3       | 2        | Y      |
| 4       | 1        | X      |
| 4       | 2        | A      |
| 4       | 3        | Y      |
+---------+----------+--------+
```

In each `session` there can be one or multiple `actions` recorded (e.g. A, X, Y and Z). The same actions can occur multiple times per session (e.g. session 1 has action A twice).

We would like to know:

- How often is an action "A" the first action in the session (that is, it has actionNr == 1)?
- How often is some action other than "A" the first action in the session (and an "A" comes at later place)?

Sessions that do not contain *any* action "A" are not interesting for the analysis and should be ignored. (For example, session 3 has only "X" and "Y" but no "A", therefore it should be ignored.)

However, if a session does contain an "A" (at any position), we are interested in it and would like to know if one of the "A"s in the session was at first position or not.

In the above example, the expected output is as follows:

```
+---------+-------------+
+ session | a was first | 
+---------+-------------+
| 1       | true        |
| 2       | true        |
| 4       | false       |
+---------+-------------+
```

My question is, what is a good way to approach this in Spark? I have some rudimentary ideas that I could try it using window functions and / or `groupBy`, but I get stuck when working out details.

Any suggestions would be very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilise the fact that (most) SQL aggregations skip null values. If we had something like this

```
+---------+----------+--------+
| session | actionNr | action |
+---------+----------+--------+
| 1       | 1        | A      |
| 1       | 2        | A      |
| 1       | null     | X      |
| 1       | 4        | A      |
| 2       | 1        | A      |
| 2       | null     | X      |
| 2       | null     | Y      |
| 3       | null     | X      |
| 3       | null     | Y      |
| 4       | null     | X      |
| 4       | 2        | A      |
| 4       | null     | Y      |
+---------+----------+--------+
```

the problem starts to look much easier. If we group by `session` and take the minimum `actionNr` we get `min(1,2,null,4)=1`, `min(1,null)=1`, `min(null,null,null,null)=null` and `min(null,2,null)=2`:

```
df.groupBy("session")
  .agg(min(when($"action" === "A", $"actionNr")) as "first_a")
  .show()
```

```
+-------+-------+
|session|first_a|
+-------+-------+
|      1|      1|
|      3|   null|
|      4|      2|
|      2|      1|
+-------+-------+
```

which can be polished to the desired format:

```
df.groupBy("session")
  .agg(min(when($"action" === "A", $"actionNr")) as "first_a")
  .filter($"first_a".isNotNull)
  .select($"session", when($"first_a" === 1, true).otherwise(false) as "a was first")
  .show()
```

```
+-------+-----------+
|session|a was first|
+-------+-----------+
|      1|       true|
|      4|      false|
|      2|       true|
+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Here only the rows where `action` equals `A` are of interest, so filter those out first. Then create a new column with 1 where `actionNr` equals 1 otherwise 0 and aggregate it grouping by `session`. This will give 1 for sessions that have `A` for `actionNr == 1` while all other rows will be 0. Finally, convert to a boolean.

This can be done as follows:

```
df.filter($"action" === "A")
  .withColumn("first", when($"actionNr" === 1, 1).otherwise(0))
  .groupBy("session").agg(sum("first").as("first"))
  .select($"session", when($"first" === 1, true).otherwise(false).as("a was first"))
```